# Foreach in a foreach + CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I got an image upload function working, but there's 4 images required in this image. And my current function is simply just overwriting the image despite the number. I'm wondering how I would insert (preferably) a letter into my foreach function.

```
$uploads = array($this->uploads->data());
foreach ( $uploads as $key[] => $value )  
{
$imagename = $cleaned . '-s' . $value['file_ext']; //outputs clean-name-s.ext
}
```

By the time all is said and done, 4 images will require this function. Leaving me with
clean-name-sa.ext, clean-name-sb.ext, clean-name-sc.ext, and clean-name-sd.ext (numbers work as well).

The form does require that all 4 fields are filled out before submission, so would I just create an array of my desired identifiers and create a foreach loop that outputs 4 different $imagenames? Or is there a simpler, more logical approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, as you've provided no indication of how the HTML is set up. If you really want an array, you can do this:

```
$uploads = array($this->uploads->data());
foreach ($uploads as $key => $value) {
   foreach (Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') as $letter) {
      $imagename = $cleaned . '-s' . $letter . '.' . $value['file_ext']; //outputs clean-name-sX.ext
      // Do something with $imagename here
   }
}
```

Note also I changed `$key[]` to `$key`.

Comment: It's a pretty simple form section `<input type="file" name="screen(a-d)">`  Using your idea, I managed to get it to upload the first file with **sa** but the others did not move.  Would putting the inputs as an array screen[] instead of individually make this easier?  If I really knew how to utilize this site formatting wise I'd post my controller and model...

Comment: Posting the entire controller and model would be too much; only a *complete*, *minimal* testcase is desired.

What do you mean by "the others did not move"? What *actually* happened?

Comment: **Controller** Uploads images -> `foreach ( $_FILES as $key => $value)` if upload is successful, move to model. **Model** Thumbnails, renames, and moves files. (load image_lib/create cleanname) -> `foreach ( $uploads as $key => $value ) { $config['new_image'] = './path/to/'.$imagename; $this->image_lib->resize(); rename($value['full_path'], '/path/to/'.$imagename;`

Comment: That's not a testcase and does not help us. :)

Using an array instead will make your life easier but it's impossible to tell at this point what your issue is currently. Put debug output through your code, like `print_r`-ing the result of $_FILES, and writing `echo` statements to track program flow.

Comment: That is essentially how it all works out, I'm actually using http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/80610/ seeing as there's really no information regarding multiple file uploading, and posting at the CI forums has yielded me almost no results for help or guidance. I don't even really know what I'm talking about to be quite frank.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit lost on your 'cleaned' section..  I dont know if you didnt include all the code or... ?

As for it overwriting the $imagename - in your loop you keep changing the value of $imagename...  So you need to have that be an array..

As for adding letters to the names.. thats easy..  just start off with 97 for 'a'  and then add to it...  wherever you want the letter use chr()   (also changed $imagname to an array)

```
// 97 is asci for 'a'
$currentChar = 97;  
$imagename = array();

$uploads = array($this->uploads->data()); 
foreach ( $uploads as $key => $value )   { 
    $imagename[] = $cleaned . '-s' . chr($currentChar) . $value['file_ext'];
     //outputs clean-name-s.ext 
     $currentChar++;
}
```

Comment: I didn't include everything, but I actually managed to get all of this working on the controller itself. I used an array containing the field name and what I wanted appended to the file name, then looped it through with that. My problem now is figuring out how to return the error during the loop without breaking things and then returning the file information for insertion to the database.